# confirmation on direct/inverse limits

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Denote by $\lim$ both $\varprojlim$ and $\varinjlim$. Say that for every $n$ the $G_n$'s are groups. Assume that $\lim_{n\ge m} G_n\simeq G$ for some $m$. Is it true that also $\lim_nG_n\simeq G$? (i.e. we can discard the first terms). Thinking to the trivial example where the maps are given by inclusions and we have topological spaces instead of groups, then we know that the direct limit is the union while the inverse limit is the intersection, so that the claim is trivially true if I am not wrong. I guess that this should be true also for rings, groups etc. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\lim_{n\geq m}$? What diagram are you taking the limit or colimit of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $ I $ be the quasi-order set.

1.If $I$ is directed(that is,$\forall i,j\in I,\exists k\in I$ such that $i,j≤k$.)$C\subset I$ is called cofinal subset of $I$ if $\forall i\in I$,$\exists j\in C$ such that $j≥i$ in $I$.If $C\subset I$ is cofinal,then $lim_{\rightarrow_{i\in I}}G_i=lim_{\rightarrow_{j\in C}}G_j$.
(If $I$ is not directed,this maybe false.)

2.for any quasi-order set $I$,if $C\subset I$ is cofinal,then the
$lim_{\leftarrow_{i\in I}}G_i=lim_{\leftarrow_{j\in C}}G_j$.this do not need directed set.

Comment: to be precise you mean $j\ge i$ right?

Comment: @Blacksmith I is a quasi-direct set.$j＞i$ is compare in $I$.you can read homological algebra.Such as Rotman.